# How to use ViewPager in a AlertDialog? - Android 4.0+

Tags: android, dialog, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I am trying to show a dialog when user clicks on the button. In the dialog, I want to create a viewpager to show multiple fragments.

Please give me a example or tutorial.
I searched and used many example code. But they still cannot work.

EDIT: My current code

- The class for customizing the dialog

  ```
    public class ViewPagerInDialog {

    private final ActionBarActivity context;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private int currentLv = 1;

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;
    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager pager;

    public ViewPagerInDialog(ActionBarActivity context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void show(){
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.level_dialog, null, false);

        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new     ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(context.getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(currentLv - 1);

        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog a = builder.create();
        a.show();
    }
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Fragment currentFragment;

    public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
        return currentFragment;
    }

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new LevelFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        if (getCurrentFragment() != object) {
            currentFragment = ((Fragment) object);
        }
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
    }
    }
  ```
- dialog layout: a LinearLayout contains the ViewPager

  ```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue" />
  ```
- LevelFragment:

  ```
    public class LevelFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.experience, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
  ```

  }

=> To show dialog:

```
 private void showLevels() {
    ViewPagerInDialog dialog = new ViewPagerInDialog((ActionBarActivity) getActivity());
    dialog.show();
    }
```

This can show the dialog but with only the blue background. The ViewPager cannot slide as I want.

Comment: A dialog is just a `ViewGroup. What's the problem to put a `ViewPager` into `ViewGroup`?

Comment: I've already tried. We will need to build a adapter and use Fragment for ViewPager. It can not work if we inflate ViewPager like other views

Answer (score 1):

[AlertDialog.Builder.setView(View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(android.view.View)) is the method which allows to add a custom view in the dialog content area.

You can inflate a compound view which derives from `ViewPager`; or create a new `ViewPager`  instance when using this method.

Comment: @GoldChicken Please revert to your original question. Then open a new question with the updated details. This way question/answer is simple to track from other users. Let me know if you create the new one to look at the issue.